# Force not suppressing confirmation prompt - removal of directories by name from any level of a directory hierarchy

Tags: powershell, recursion, prompt, subdirectory, confirmation

I have following the PowerShell script to delete folders out of my other project:

```
 param([Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$path)
     $directories = dir -Path $path -Directory -Recurse 

     foreach ($directory in $directories){
        if ($directory.Name  -eq "bin" -or $directory.Name -eq "obj"){
            Remove-Item -Path $directory.FullName -Force -Confirm:$false
        }
     }
```

And if I use it, there always is a prompt

```
Confirm
The item at C:\Users\...\bin has children and the
Recurse parameter was not specified. If you continue, all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want
 to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

I know that adding `-Recurse` to the `Remove-Item` cmdlet should do the thing, but this is redundant and because of it there is a possibility for the code to create exceptions. So how do I suppress that confirmation prompt?

Comment: What do you mean by "there is a possibility for the code to create exceptions"?

Comment: You need to specify `-Recurse`.  Also `-Confirm:$false` is meaningless.  **Switches are false by default**.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart -Recurse is good for deleting files, not directories, because it does not have a certain order for removing, so it can remove a folder, that is containing other folders referenced by the foreach inside the -Recurse and not yet deleted

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 that is _usually_ the case, but not when it comes to overriding `ComfirmImpact` levels

Comment: Properly written recursion would not generate an exception. I have never had that issue either.

Comment: @EBGreen this is how the standard -Recurse works with directories

Comment: I am not able to reproduce (at least when the user running the command has appropriate permissions).

Comment: I have never had -Recurse generate exceptions

Comment: If you don't like `-Confirm` or it won't behave recursively (for whatever reason) you can always try setting `$ConfirmPreference` to `None`, but be sure to use `try .. finally` to restore it to its proper value (or play with scopes, but I'm not sure that's going to work).

Comment: In my experience (and I just tested it) -Confirm:$false works fine with recursion.

Comment: @EBGreen if you have a big project written on c#, try to start the powershell script with -Recurse on its directory, you will get many errors, because every bin and obj directory has many sub-directories

Comment: I have deleted huge directory trees in the past with no exceptions. @mklement0 spotted the problem. You are removing items outside the recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I agree that `-Confirm:$False` should suppress the confirmation prompt even in the absence of `-Recurse`, even if it did, the removal would still invariably be *recursive*.

**Your real problem is the use of a `foreach` *statement*, which invariably creates the list of directories *up front*** (even if you used `foreach ($dir in Get-ChildItem ...)`, and therefore potentially attempts to access directories that were already removed in a previous iteration, as part of a previously removed directory's subtree.

By contrast, **using the *pipeline* directly with `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory` handles the recursive enumeration gracefully** by not enumerating subdirs. that a previous iteration has already removed:

```
 param([Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$path)

 # Note the use of the pipeline and the ForEach-Object cmdlet.
 Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Name  -eq "bin" -or $_.Name -eq "obj"){
        Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$False -LiteralPath $_.FullName
    }
 }
```

The above can be simplified to:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory -Recurse -Include bin, obj | 
  Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$False
```